# Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#

I'm getting an unusual error when trying to build my newly created ASP.NET Core 6 project. Although it was working fine for the last few days, this error started appearing suddenly:

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
> module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets

I tried changing the platform target to other options like x64 or x86, but this problem doesn't seem to come from the project itself. That is because, I created another project to see if it's still appearing. Turns out that this error being thrown even when I build my newly created project.

What could possibly go wrong? Should I reinstall Visual Studio 2022 (Community edition)?

**EDIT**
Rebooting the system fixed it. This could probably be an issue in my hard disk too as Hans Passant has mentioned in the comments section below.

Comment: can you commit a reproducing project to github and share?

Comment: Don't do anything drastic.  Reinstalling VS won't fix it.  Run chkdsk first to see how much damage was done.  If you see a bunch of errors then replace the disk drive.  If not, delete the file from the nuget cache.  Best to have a look at it first with a hex viewer, if it is filled with zeros then get rid of the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: System.Memory.dll is part of the runtime. (it's typically located at `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.2`) Try reinstalling the .net 6.0 sdk.